# Is there any subgroup in $S_5$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We have the group $S_5$. Which of the following statement is false:

> $1)$ $S_5$ contains a cyclic group of order $6$
>
> $2)$ $S_5$ contains a non-Abelian  subgroup of order  $8$
>
> $3)$ $S_5$ does not contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$
>
> $4)$ $S_5$ does not contain a subgroup of order $7$

**Solution I tried**

$1)$ $S_5$ has $20$ elements of order $6$ so it will have a subgroup of order $6$

$4)$ A group of order $7$ is cyclic but $S_5$ has no element of order $7$ ,so there will be no subgroup of order $7$

I have doubts about the options $3$ and $2$.

For the option $2)$: here the order of the group is $8=2^3$. By Sylow's theorem there can be $1,3,5$ or $15$ 2-Sylow subgroups of order $8$; but how to check which one is non-abelian?

For the option $3)$: I have to check if there is any subgroup which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$, *i.e* I have to check if there is any non cyclic abelian group of order $4$ in $S_5$. I am not getting how to proceed further, please provide me a hint.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: consider two disjoint transpositions.

Answer (score 5):

More generally, every group of order $\leqslant n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$. This is essentially a consequence of [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem). Indeed a group $G$ is a subgroup of the symmetric group of order $|G|$.

Comment: Thus option $3$ is false.

Comment: but still confusion here because according to Cayley's theorem "If $G$ is a group of order $n$ then $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ ,but here group is of order $4$  then how can we say that there will be a subgroup in $S_5$  which is isomorphic to that group?

Comment: I suppose you know that $S_4$ is a subgroup of $S_5$.

Comment: I try to search this result in my book but there is nothing related to this result,can you please tell me in which book i can find this result?

Comment: $S_5$ is the group of permutations on $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. What is the subset of $S_5$ containing the permutations $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(5) = 5$ ?

Comment: Is there any difference between  $(1~2~3~4)$ and $(1~2~3~4)(5)$ ?

Comment: @Grv saini, Yes, there is. $S_4$ is just *isomorphic* to a subgroup of $S_5$. Technically, $S_4\cap S_5=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\{(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$

Comment: That's not a "hint".

Comment: but how to select these $4$ elements from those $2$ order $35$ elements?

Comment: Since this subgroup lives in $S_4$ being a subgroup of $S_5$.

Comment: @Lee Mosher, this is certainly a hint: you still need to prove that this subset a subgroup and it shows to start with small examples.

Comment: just one thing i hope you will help me , The answer by @J.-E. Pin he also saying that $S_4$ is subgroup of $S_5$ ,but one question that  stuck in my mind is  $(1)(2)(3)(4)$ is same as $(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$ .?

Comment: If you write $(1)$ or $(2)$ or $(5)$ that is all the same thing, namely the identity $(1)$. So $(12)(34)(5)$ is the same as $(12)(34)$. Is that the answer to your question about $S_4$ being a subgroup of $S_5$?

Comment: @NickyHekster, I guess that the OP has intuitively (and correctly) in mind that, technically, $S_4\cap S_5=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

For $(3)$,
$|\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}|=4 , $ this not a cyclic group, hence its isomorphic to $K_4 \approx \{I,(13),(24), (13)(24)\}$